# Replying to a message in mu4e causes Emacs to hang/freeze entirely. How can I fix this?

Tags: mu4e

From any message in mu4e, triggering a reply causes Emacs to hang entirely, becoming totally unresponsive. It doesn't respond to `C-g`, or anything else. I can stop the process with `kill -SIGUSR2 <pid>` and the pid for emacs, which returns this trace:

```
Debugger entered--entering a function:
* #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x224abfe4452e83>)()
  file-name-sans-extension("1677909917.c0b552d026d119d4.jon-laptop:2,DS")
  org-element-org-data-parser()
  org-element--parse-to(1)
  org-element--cache-verify-element((paragraph (:begin 1 :end 436 :contents-begin 1 :contents-end 436 :post-blank 0 :post-affiliated 1 :mode top-comment :granularity element :cached t :parent (section (:begin 1 :end 2268 :contents-begin 1 :contents-end 2267 :robust-begin 1 :robust-end 2265 :post-blank 1 :post-affiliated 1 :mode first-section :granularity element :cached t :parent (org-data (:begin 1 :contents-begin 1 :contents-end 2267 :end 2268 :robust-begin 3 :robust-end 2265 :post-blank 1 :post-affiliated 1 :path "/home/jon/Mail/columbia/[Gmail]/Drafts/cur/1677909..." :mode org-data :CATEGORY "1677909917.c0b552d026d119d4" :cached t)))))))
  org-element-at-point()
  org-adaptive-fill-function()
  fill-match-adaptive-prefix()
  fill-context-prefix(96 140)
  #<subr adaptive-wrap-fill-context-prefix>(96 140)
  funcall(#<subr adaptive-wrap-fill-context-prefix> 96 140)
  (let ((adaptive-wrap-extra-indent (+word-wrap--calc-extra-indent beg))) (funcall fn beg end))
  +word-wrap--adjust-extra-indent-a(#<subr adaptive-wrap-fill-context-prefix> 96 140)
  apply(+word-wrap--adjust-extra-indent-a #<subr adaptive-wrap-fill-context-prefix> (96 140))
  adaptive-wrap-fill-context-prefix(96 140)
  adaptive-wrap-prefix-function(96 1596)
  #f(compiled-function (fun) #<bytecode 0x19a2f352921943fd>)(adaptive-wrap-prefix-function)
  jit-lock--run-functions(96 1596)
  jit-lock-fontify-now(96 1596)
  jit-lock-function(96)
  redisplay_internal\ \(C\ function\)()
```

Something's apparently in some kind of infinite loop or recursive something. How can I fix this?

Edit: [I found this reddit thread which describes the same thing, although there doesn't appear to be a solution included in it.](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/oizpz8/mu4e_composing_a_reply_sometimes_freezes_the/)

[I also found this bug in org-msg,](https://github.com/jeremy-compostella/org-msg/issues/154) but I don't think it's related to org-msg, since disabling the package doesn't fix this issue.

This is probably some kind of recursive problem with adaptive-wrap or word wrap, since I also get a freeze by enabling global-word-wrap-mode.

Comment: No idea if this is the issue, but I notice that that filename contains both `:` and `,` characters. I believe `:` in a filename is a problem for some filesystems. Might that be a possible cause?

Comment: I'd say that the problem lies in a filename not supported by `file-name-sans-extension`  or an unexpected return from it as the filename which will be just `1677909917.c0b552d026d119d4` in this case.

Comment: Those filenames are how the maildir format stores emails on the filesystem. There's no problem with them, since that's always been the way mbsync/isync stores the emails, and how mu accesses them. Plus, I've had no issues with anything email related, in or out of emacs, in years. The problem instead is with how the emails are displayed. Something in font-lock or word-wrap is in an infinite loop.